# Detect device make, model and version (where provided) in PHP

Tags: php, mobile, tablet

I'm trying to detect the user's device details (make, model, version - where provided) with PHP.

I don't just want to detect if it's a mobile or tablet ([mdetect](https://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/PHP/mdetect.php) and [MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) do this very well), I want to get as many details as can be ascertained and then present this in a formatted way.

An example use would be "Edited Monday 9.15pm on a Galaxy S3", or "Edited on a PC", or "on an iPhone".

I understand that the way to do this will be via the useragent, but I'm hoping that someone's had a crack at formatting this in a nice way already. I also understand that the full details wont always be available (for instance the iPhone provides iOS version but not iPhone model).

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely Useragent parsers out there. CodeIgniter has a library built-in.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html

Comment: Thanks Crunch, I've had a look and the Codeigniter library certainly seems to name a fair few mobile models, which is very useful, but I feel it would be possible to go further. For those interested, the list of what Codeigniter's User Agent library detects can be seen here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/user_agents.php